# merging json array only with same keys

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have two Json arrays like below:

```
$a='[{"type":"text","req":0,"name":"user"},{"type":"text","req":0,"name":"org"},'
        . '{"type":"textarea","label":"Notes","req":0},'
        . '{"type":"text","label":"text1","req":0},'
        . '{"type":"textarea","label":"Notes","req":0},'
        . '{"type":"text","label":"text2","req":0},'
        . '{"type":"textarea","label":"Notes","req":1}]';

$b='[{"type":"textarea","label":"Notes","Element_Values":"331","Element_Name":"textarea-710091","Count_Images":0},'
        . '{"type":"text","label":"text1","Element_Values":"1","Element_Name":"text-987351","Count_Images":0},'
        . '{"type":"textarea","label":"Notes","Element_Values":"332","Element_Name":"textarea-254458","Count_Images":0},'
        . '{"type":"text","label":"text2","Element_Values":"2","Element_Name":"text-3410","Count_Images":0},'
        . '{"type":"textarea","label":"Notes","Element_Values":"333","Element_Name":"textarea-554051","Count_Images":0}]';
```

As you can see array 'a' starts with few keys which is not in array 'b'. I want to skip the arrays which has 'name' keys.

I did the following code, but didnt work:

```
  $c = [];
$aJson=json_decode($a, true);
$bJson=json_decode($b, true);
foreach($aJson as $key => $array)
{
    foreach($array as $an)
    {
        if(array_key_exists('name', $an)) 
        {
            //continue;        
        }
    }


        $c[$key] = array_merge($bJson[$key],$array);

}
echo json_encode($c);
```

The result array c should be:

```
[{"type":"textarea","label":"Notes","Element_Values":"331","Element_Name":"textarea-710091","Count_Images":0,"req":0},{"type":"text","label":"text1","Element_Values":"1","Element_Name":"text-987351","Count_Images":0,"req":0},{"type":"textarea","label":"Notes","Element_Values":"332","Element_Name":"textarea-254458","Count_Images":0,"req":0},{"type":"text","label":"text2","Element_Values":"2","Element_Name":"text-3410","Count_Images":0,"req":0},{"type":"textarea","label":"Notes","Element_Values":"333","Element_Name":"textarea-554051","Count_Images":0,"req":1}]
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple debug problem, `$array` is already the array.

```
$index = 0;
foreach($aJson as $key => $array)
{
    if(isset($array['name'])) 
        continue;        

    $c[$index] = array_merge($bJson[$index], $array);
    $index++;
}
```

Comment: Just a comment, but in your desired result you have this included:

{"type":"textarea","label":"Notes","Element_Values":"331","Element_Name":"textarea-710091","Count_Images":0,"req":0}.  "req":0 is in there ?